# Why am in receiving org.sonar.sslr.grammar.GrammarException exception on Sonarqube scan?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am having a problem with Sonarqube running from with gradle within a Jenkins pipeline. I am using sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778, gradle 4.3, and the gradle Sonarqube plugin version 2.6.1

When running, we are getting an error that a file cannot be analyzed but there is no reason. When I turn on the '--stacktrace' I am getting the error below error and I have found NO reference to anyone else getting this in any of my searches. Does anyone know what the following mean?

> Caused by: org.sonar.sslr.grammar.GrammarException: The inner part of
>   ZeroOrMore and OneOrMore must not allow empty matches     at
>   org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Instruction$CommitVerifyInstruction.execute(Instruction.java:277)
>     at org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.execute(Machine.java:162)     at
>   org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.execute(Machine.java:105)  at
>   org.sonar.sslr.internal.vm.Machine.parse(Machine.java:83)     at
>   org.sonar.sslr.parser.ParseRunner.parse(ParseRunner.java:46)  at
>   com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.parse(ActionParser.java:101)    at
>   com.sonar.sslr.api.typed.ActionParser.parse(ActionParser.java:97)     at
>   org.sonar.java.ast.parser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:55)    at
>   org.sonar.java.ast.parser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:32)    at
>   org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:94)
>     ... 70 more

Comment: This feels like a bug in Sonarqube

Comment: @Matt Goodnight: Did you figure this out?
I'm running into the same problem.
Please post any progress you made in solving / troubleshooting this.